# MRG_MyISAM with myisampack tables blocking inserts

Tags: mysql, myisam, mariadb

I'm using `INSERT_METHOD=FIRST` and compressing all tables that are members of the union but when I try to insert into the `MRG_MyISAM` table it tries to insert into the second one (instead of the first).  **Why?**  When I uncompress the 2nd table and insert again, it tries to insert into the 3rd.  It gives an error that the table is read-only which I'm fully aware.  This behavior is unexpected.

`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

My MRG_MyISAM table looks like:

`` CREATE TABLE `ah_sales` (
 `server` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `itemId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `countof` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `seller` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `buyer` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `saleon` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 KEY `buyer` (`buyer`),
 KEY `itemserver` (`countof`,`server`,`itemId`),
 KEY `seller` (`seller`)
) ENGINE=MRG_MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 INSERT_METHOD=FIRST UNION=(`ah_sales_4_2014`,`ah_sales_4_2013`,`ah_sales_8_2012`,`ah_sales_4_2012`,`ah_sales_12_2011`,`ah_sales_6_2011`,`ah_sales_3_2011`,`ah_sales_12_2010`,`ah_sales_6_2010`,`ah_sales_3_2010`,`ah_sales_11_2009`,`ah_sales_8_2009`,`ah_sales_5_2009`,`ah_sales_2_2009`,`ah_sales_11_2008`,`ah_sales_8_2008`,`ah_sales_5_2008`,`ah_sales_2_2008`,`ah_sales_11_2007`,`ah_sales_9_2007`,`ah_sales_8_2007`,`ah_sales_6_2007`,`ah_sales_5_2007`,`ah_sales_3_2007`,`ah_sales_2_2007`,`ah_sales_1_2007`,`ah_sales_12_2006`,`ah_sales_11_2006`,`ah_sales_10_2006`,`ah_sales_9_2006`,`ah_sales_8_2006`) ``

`ah_sales_4_2014` is uncompressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug. In essence, it sounds like the `Mrg_MyISAM` definition must be using the structure of the first member of the `UNION` clause as the basis for the rest the tables in the list.

Before you report the bug, try reversing the order of the `UNION` clause so that all the compressed tables are first and the uncompressed one is last

```
CREATE TABLE `ah_sales` (
 `server` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `itemId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `countof` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `seller` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `buyer` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `saleon` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 KEY `buyer` (`buyer`),
 KEY `itemserver` (`countof`,`server`,`itemId`),
 KEY `seller` (`seller`)
) ENGINE=MRG_MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
INSERT_METHOD=LAST
UNION=(`ah_sales_4_2013`,`ah_sales_8_2012`,
`ah_sales_4_2012`,`ah_sales_12_2011`,`ah_sales_6_2011`,
`ah_sales_3_2011`,`ah_sales_12_2010`,`ah_sales_6_2010`,
`ah_sales_3_2010`,`ah_sales_11_2009`,`ah_sales_8_2009`,
`ah_sales_5_2009`,`ah_sales_2_2009`,`ah_sales_11_2008`,
`ah_sales_8_2008`,`ah_sales_5_2008`,`ah_sales_2_2008`,
`ah_sales_11_2007`,`ah_sales_9_2007`,`ah_sales_8_2007`,
`ah_sales_6_2007`,`ah_sales_5_2007`,`ah_sales_3_2007`,
`ah_sales_2_2007`,`ah_sales_1_2007`,`ah_sales_12_2006`,
`ah_sales_11_2006`,`ah_sales_10_2006`,`ah_sales_9_2006`,
`ah_sales_8_2006`,`ah_sales_4_2014`);
```

Then, see if the problem persists. Either way, you may have to submit a short or long bug report.

IMHO, running myisampack across all MyISAM tables is a good idea PROVIDED YOU ONLY SELECT FROM ALL THE TABLES. I do not believe it was meant to be used the way you are doing it (performing INSERTs when there is a mix of compressed and uncompressed). I do not think you will have this problem if all the MyISAM tables were uncompressed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  A quote from the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/merge-storage-engine.html "However, any or all of the MyISAM tables can be compressed with myisampack"  

I am going to uncompress them and see if it works.  I  have been using this structure (uncompressed) for many years as you can see.  I just thought I would try to save some space with myisampack since only the first partition get inserts.